# Multi level view: expandablelistview

Tags: android, treeview, expandablelistview

I am trying to write multi level tree. I did look at expandablelistview, but it only supports two levels. I did look at other questions(SO) & posts and the most promising post i have found is http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/02/3-level-expandable-lists.html

I understand that i will have to write something custom to handle multiple level tree.
What is the best recommended approach to take?
Can i add an exapandablelistview as a child to an exapanablelistview??

Thanks

Comment: found one more link that does something similar http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html#comment-form

Comment: also found this http://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/

Comment: See is the link for My project where N-level Tree list view can be achieved.https://github.com/Jaldips/Android-MultilevelTreeListView

Comment: I've had good experiences with `tree-view-list-android`, which is now at https://github.com/Polidea/tree-view-list-android. There hasn't been much activity lately, but the code works and I got the result I wanted from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve an n-level `ExpandableListView`, if you use it with your custom `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.

In this extended adapter, you override the

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, 
    View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

method, assign a BaseExpandableListAdapter instance to the convertView, and return it.

If you have override all the necessary methods in your adapter, this should work.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but it would make the GUI structure too complicated to implement.

First, you have to know that the items rendered of `ExpandableListView` are given by a `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. You have to design and implement the same number of adapters as your level-2 items, so that the level-3 lists can be rendered correctly for each level-2 item.

I would suggest you to redesign the GUI. Multilevel `ExpandableListView` not only complicate the code, maybe also mess up the screen.