# Dynamically creating groups within another groups in android using expandablelistview.

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have developed one expandablelistview successfully. Now I need to use expandable listview within another expandablelistview. How to create groups within another groups in android expandablelistview. Please help me. How to do implement it.

This is my code for creating 2 groups (orderinfo, customerinfo).

```
final LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> headerData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    final HashMap<String, String> group1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    group1.put(NAME, "OrderInfo");
    headerData.add( group1 );

    final HashMap<String, String> group2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    group2.put(NAME, "CustomerInfo");
    headerData.add( group2);
```

Now I need to implement the customerinfo within another 3 group which are created. How to do this. Please give me sample code.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a **standard** expandablelistview I'd suggest looking at the samples:

Path: android-sdk\samples\android-8\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\view

- ExpandableList1.java
- ExpandableList2.java
- ExpandableList3.java

If you want **more than 2 lvls** read on from here:

I haven't done this before but I believe what you are trying to achieve is a n-th order exanpdablelistview. There is another post here that might be interesting for you: [Multi level view: expandablelistview](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5639090/969325)

From another post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8352750/969325 it seems like you wont be able to achieve this with regular expandablelistview and you therefor have to either:

1. Make your own expandablelistview from scatch.
2. Use an expandablelistview for the first 2 lvls and make the last levels with linearlayout etc.
3. Make everything with views that are layered inside a scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Three Level Expandable list](http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.in/2011/09/three-level-expandable-list.html) .